# Blank a column if a condition is met

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a established a custom list with 5 columns for testing.

1. Title column
2. Date columns (Date1 & Date2)
3. Calculated column to count days between the 2 dates (Total)
4. Calculated column to count how long it was since the first date column was entered (How Long).

What I am trying to accomplish is that when the "Date2" column is filled the "How Long" column will blank out.

Example:

[image]

So in this case because there is a date in the "Date2" column I want the "How Long" column to be blank. The current formula for my "How Long" column is simple: `=Date1-TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy")`.

Is it possible to add additional syntax that will blank the "How Long" out when a date is entered into "Date2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ISBLANK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/is-functions-586532cc-9888-4ca0-98b8-c874e4c8a087) Syntax, as Matiur Rahman provided.

But the formula should be:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Date2)),"",Date1-TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Date2),"",Date1-TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if the date column is blank or not, you can use **ISBLANK** function in your formula.

Example:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date Column]), "Date column is blank", "Date column is filled")
```

So, in your case you need to update your formula like below:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date2]), [Date1]-TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy"), "")
```

**Reference**: [IS functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/is-functions-586532cc-9888-4ca0-98b8-c874e4c8a087) - Check for `ISBLANK` example